# Still waiting for db to be ready... Or maybe the db is not reachable. 59 attempts left

Tags: docker, symfony, doctrine

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        SKELETON: ${SKELETON:-symfony/skeleton}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@gk_app:3567/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8
      # Run "composer require symfony/mercure-bundle" to install and configure the Mercure integration
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp

# Mercure is installed as a Caddy module, prevent the Flex recipe from installing another service
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB: ${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: "3.4"

# Development environment override
services:
  php:
    volumes:
      # The "cached" option has no effect on Linux but improves performance on Mac
      - ./:/srv/app:rw,cached
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/symfony.dev.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/symfony.ini
      # If you develop on Mac you can remove the var/ directory from the bind-mount
      # for better performance by enabling the next line
      - ./var/storage:/srv/app/var/storage:rw
    environment:
      APP_ENV: dev

  caddy:
    volumes:
      - ./docker/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile:ro
      - ./public:/srv/app/public:ro

###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    ports:
      - "3567:3306"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> blackfireio/blackfire-symfony-meta ###
  blackfire:
    image: blackfire/blackfire:2
    # uncomment to store Blackfire credentials in a local .env.local file
    #env_file: .env.local
    environment:
      BLACKFIRE_LOG_LEVEL: 4
    ports: [8307]
###< blackfireio/blackfire-symfony-meta ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
  mailer:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports: [1025, 1080]
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

I run:-
`HTTP_PORT=8080 HTTPS_PORT=8443 SERVER_NAME=foo.localhost docker-compose up` and get the error above with it counting down to zero. The containers/services fail to launch?

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

I've tried `DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@gk_app:3567/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8` with different ports: `3567` & `3306` with no success?

Is anyone savvy with https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/docker-compose.yml and swapping `postgres` for `mysql`?

**Edit**:
Trying:-
`DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@localhost:3567/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8`,

`DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@127.0.0.1:3567/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8`

& `DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@database:3567/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8`

all of these produce the same error?

Comment: No service `depends_on` the database, so I don't see why it would fail with that error message. But anyways, in the envvar `DATABASE_URL` you define `gk_app` as the database host, but no service goes by that name. Is it an entry on your `/etc/hosts` or reacheable any other way? If not, try adding `container_name: gk_app` to the `database:` section.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the port configuration. The database port exposed to the internal network is still 3306, so you should use `mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@database:3306/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=8.0&charset=utf8`. `localhost` would refer to the container running the `php` service. You can use the 3567 to access the database using `localhost` _from the host computer_ (i.e. the "real" one")

Comment: OK, so with: `DATABASE_URL: mysql://${MYSQL_USER:-root}:${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}@database:3306/${MYSQL_DB:-gk_app}?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8` I still receive the error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DATABASE_URL is checked without comments: https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/pull/107

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question, but I got the same problem and I solved the issue adding these drivers in Dockerfile

```
UN set -eux; \
    install-php-extensions \
        apcu \
        intl \
        opcache \
        zip \
        sockets \
        amqp \
        pdo \
        mysqli\
        pdo_mysql\
    ;
```

Also was able to run against local mysql database setting up the connection as follows

```
mysql://youruser:youpassword@host.docker.internal:3306/yourdatabse?serverVersion=8.0.30
```

But don't forget to allow external connections to your local mysql binding the 0.0.0.0 in mysql config file -**only for development**-.